# how to use the template in this situation

Tags: c++

I have made a template like this:

```
template<class T>
void changeLength1D(T*& a[], int oldLength, int newLength)
{

    T* temp = new T[newLength];
    int number = min(newLength, oldLength);
    copy(a, a + number, temp);
    delete[] a;
    a = temp;
}
```

when I want use this template：

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
#include"changeLength1D.h"

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 6,5,8,4,3,1 };

    int n = 6;
    changeLength1D(*a[], n,4);

    copy(a, a + n, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

what should I put in the first parameter？

Comment: Why do you think you could delete the array that you allocated on the stack? Use std::vector!

Comment: What is `T*& a[]` supposed to be? An array of references?

Comment: The first argument to `changeLength1D` should probably be `T* a` and you call it with `changeLength1D(a, n,4);`.  Of course your code will cause segmentation fault anyway.

Comment: It is an array.

Answer (score 1):

One neat trick: you can find the size of an array with templates so don't need to pass it in.

```
template<size_t n> 
int f(int(&c)[n])
{
}
```

can be called on an array and n is the size.

If we change your template slightly, we can use this, so then pass one fewer parameter, but I will make other changes so we don't delete things that were on the stack:

```
template<class T, int oldLength>
T * changeLength1D_again(T (&a)[oldLength], int newLength)
{
    T* temp = new T[newLength];
    int number = min(newLength, oldLength);
    copy(a, a + number, temp);
    //delete[] a; may have been on stack - so no.
    //a = temp; //again, if was on stack, no
    return temp;
}
```

Then just call like this

```
int * changed = changeLength1D_again(a, 4);
copy(changed, changed + n, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

This way, it won't try to delete the original `a`.

You seem to be trying to dynamically resize stack arrays; which won't work. If you use a std::vector instead you will make your life easier.

```
std::vector<int> v={ 6,5,8,4,3,1 };
v.resize(4);  //now has just four, but some spare capacity, which might be ok
v.shrink_to_fit(); //if you need to
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am a fresh learner in C++.And I'm so happy that you can answer my question. Thank you !!!